# Background image slows down android app

Tags: java, android, performance, image, background

I am new to developing android apps. I am making an app where simple object moves. The problem is with the background. When I put code like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    BackGround1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lightning1);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BackGround1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawCircle(xp, yp, circleRadius, circlePaint);
}
```

the moving object (circle) slows down significantly and after a while (like 20 seconds) there start to appear traces from circle and after that (~10 seconds) it "crashes" and goes back to previous activity.

If I put
`canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);`
instead of
`canvas.drawBitmap(BackGround1, 0, 0, null);` then everything works fine. lightning1 is 480x800 jpg image.
  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm-gc(13262): Could not create 1097728-byte ashmem mark stack: Too many open files
04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(13262): dvmHeapBeginMarkStep failed; aborting
04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm(13262): VM aborting
04-11 02:00:50.902: ERROR/ActivityManager(92): fail to set top app changed!
```

Comment: Post the logcat if you have crashes.

Comment: 04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm-gc(13262): Could not create 1097728-byte ashmem mark stack: Too many open files
04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(13262): dvmHeapBeginMarkStep failed; aborting
04-11 02:00:50.722: ERROR/dalvikvm(13262): VM aborting
04-11 02:00:50.902: ERROR/ActivityManager(92): fail to set top app changed!
,that is the Error code I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're decoding the resource every time the surface is being drawn. This is creating many new `Bitmap` objects, and Android has more than enough work running the garbage collector over it to clean up after you.

You might want to load the resource only once, and store it in a field.

In a more general sense, you can always review Logcat to figure out what is causing a force close. I'm assuming that you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: I don't think he is creating any new objects.  He is assigning BackGround1 over and over yes, but saying he is creating many new Bitmaps is incorrect.

Comment: The [documentation on BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) states: "Decode a new Bitmap from an InputStream."

Comment: Yes I guess it was making too many objects or something like that. Problems solved by putting this chunk: BackGround1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lightning1);
at the beginning of the class and removing from that method. Thank you guys for your help.